# Выгрузка в текстовый файл в виде таблицы

Tags: python, prettytable

Вот мой код:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

def Load():
    with open ('w.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    v = list(file.read().splitlines())

    d=int(v[0])

    for i in range(len(v)):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        #Фамилии
        elif i % 2 == 1:
            sd_name=''
            sd_name+=v[i]

        #Числа
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            z = v[i]
            x = int(z[0] + z[1])
            y = int(z[3] + z[4] + z[5] + z[6])

            itogo=''
            itogo+=str(x*y)

            days=''
            days+=str(x)

            oklad=''
            oklad+=str(y)

            Calc(x,y,d,sd_name,days,oklad)


summa=[]

def Calc(x,y,d,sd_name,days,oklad):
    zrplt = round(((x*y)/d), 2)
    summa.append(zrplt)
    it = sum(summa)
    Save(zrplt,sd_name,days,oklad,it)



t = PrettyTable()
t.field_names = ["Фамилия", "Дни", "Оклад", "Зарплата"]


def Save(zrplt,sd_name,days,oklad,it):
    with open('w2.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:

        t.add_rows(
            [
                [str(sd_name),str(days),str(oklad),str(zrplt)]

            ]
        )

        t.add_row(["Итого", '','',it])
        f.write(str(t))

Load()
```

Получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А надо так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я понял, проблема в том, что строчка Итого пишется после каждого сотрудника вместо того, что-бы писаться единожды, в конце таблицы.

Если это так, то лечение состоит в том, что-бы строчку кода, которая пишет ненужные промежуточные итоги `t.add_row(["Итого", '','',it])` убрать из тела функции `Save`, которую вы вызываете циклически, после обработки данных сотрудника, и перенести связанные с ним действия -  в том числе вычисление итоговой суммы и ее запись  -  в конец функции `Load`

P.S. Использование глобальными переменными, а тем более их хаотическое определение, перемешивание в коде операторов основной функции и определения вспомогательных функций и тоже в хаотическом порядке -  крайне нехорошая практика, затрудняющая как написание кода, так и выявление и исправление ошибок в нем.

Comment: Просто в задании так написано:
2. Написать функцию Calc для вычисления зарплаты каждого работника по формуле... с округлением значения до двух десятичных знаков. Функция должна также подсчитать итоговую зарплату.

3. Написать функцию Save для выгрузки в файл ведомости заработной платы в виде следующей таблицы.

Comment: Если хотите сделать дословно, как написано в задании - делайте. Т.е. считайте свою итоговую зарплату накопительной суммой, но в таблицу записывайте так, как я вам подсказал. Если, конечно, хотите, что-бы ваш вывод выглядел так, как вы показали на рисунке.

Comment: Сделал расчёт зарплаты и добавление итоговой строки в конец функции Load(), но всё равно "Итого" вылазит после каждой фамилии

Comment: После вызова функции Load() добавил открытие файла и добавил туда "Итого", и теперь всё как надо, "Итого" только в конце.

Comment: Ну и чудесно, что вы наконец поняли что я вам писал. Правда, более корректно эти действия делать не после вызова Load, а в самой функции Load, как я вам подсказал в ответе. Но хотите "дословно, как в задании" - дело ваше. Про то, что перенос предполагает  " и перенести связанные с ним действия " я вроде написал в ответе, но вот про, что надо еще дополнительно разжевывать, что это означает открытие файла, запись в него и закрытие этого файла -  как то в голову не пришло. Все-таки тут форум программистов (ну или кандидатов на это звание)